# Get encompassing model on ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I apologize for the confusing title, the problem is quite simple.

I have a $scope.users variable. I ng-repeat them and create a input for every user's respective valid until property. On a ng-change on this input I want to send a update request on my User service. How can I get the proper user on my ng-change?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="user in users">
  <input type="date" ng-change="setValidUntil" value="{{user.validUntil}}"/>
  //...other user properties
</div>

//in appropriate controller

$scope.setValidUntil = function () {
  User.update({
   'studentNumber': $scope.user.studentNumber,  // Missing this!!
   'validUntil':validUntil
  });
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use ng-model variable and to use $scope.$watch('modelVar',function(newVal){   // update your user});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the user into the function

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="user in users" style="margin-bottom:0.5em">
<input type="date" ng-change="setValidUntil(user)" value="{{user.validUntil}}"/>
 //...other user properties
</div>

//in appropriate controller

$scope.setValidUntil = function (data) {
 //you can update your data like that.
}
```